# How to do this in c# using generics

Tags: c#, generics, .net-4.0

I have a code similar to this:

```
 int GetIntValue(string name)
 {
      string valueString=GetValue(name);
      int value=int.Parse(valueString);
      return value;
 }
 double GetDoubleValue(string name)
 {
      string valueString=GetValue(name);
      double value=double.Parse( valueString, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Any, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
      return value;
 }
```

and similar code for other type of numeric type.

I want to write something such as this:

```
  T getValue<T>(string name)
  {
      string valueString=GetValue(name);
      T value=T.Parse(valueString, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Any, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
      return value;
  }
```

But it is not working (T is too general). How can  change this code to do use generic in c#?

I am using .net 4.

## edit

Code fixed to remove typos.

Comment: here is something interesting: http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20111020084257AAtB8qA

Comment: Since the first line is the same, you are actually asking how to call Parse without providing a concrete type but expect the result to be a concrete type? Even if you could, you would still have to pass the type argument, eg `getValue<double>(value)`. Why not just call `double.ToParse` in the first place?

Comment: You will trade multiple function to a generic with sort of `switch/case` inside (not actually one, but a kind of), where you have to check *all types* what have an unique `Parse` (or perhaps if you can yourself parse them) and call it for that type. Other possibility could be a reflection, where you check if that type has `Parse` method and somehow call it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [`Convert.ChangeType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dtb69x08%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) if `T` implements [`IConvertible`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iconvertible%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
T getValue<T>(string name) where T : IConvertible
{
    string valueString=GetValue(string);
    T value = (T)Convert.ChangeType(valueString, typeof(T));
    return value;
}
```

Comment: In my code I have: value=int.TryParse(valueString, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Any, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); To make sure that local culture doesn't effect the parse result. How can I do this with this method?

Comment: You can pass `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` as a third parameter. If you actually need `Any` (as opposed to the default of [`Integer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberstyles(v=vs.110).aspx)), I'm not sure...maybe you could build that into an `IFormatProvider` you write, or maybe you'd need to just handle `int` (and any other types where you might specify a non-default `NumberStyles`) as a special case.

Answer (score 3):

Questions is how to have one generic method to parse int and double right?
In question's methods there is **string valueString=GetValue(string);** , probably TYPO so this get value

so to fit to this questions this method should look like

```
   private T Read<T>(string name)
            {
                string valueString=GetValue(name);
                TypeConverter converter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof (T));
                        try
                        {
                            return (T) converter.ConvertFromString(value);
                        }
                        catch (FormatException)
                        {
                            return default(T);
                        }

            }
```

Comment: How this is an answer?

Comment: WTF with you guys whats wrong in answer? question is how to do one method so whats wrong here?

Comment: Maybe you should add any explaination? This is not a strict answer. And BTW using acronyms does not mean that `F` is not what it is

Comment: @wudzik did you read question? he has two methods to parse double and int, In my case if you call Read<int>("11", 0) it will return 11 so whats wrong?

Comment: We're not hating, chill. Good answer should contain explaination (unless it's self explaining). Your answer is not self-explaining at all

Comment: @VolodymyrBilyachat Well for a start it won't compile. Try removing the superfluous braces... Also, a description explaining how this works and why it solves the OP's problem would help.

Comment: As @wudzik suggested, a thorough answer as opposed to just pasted code is preferred.

Comment: Yes it wont compile since was typing in text editor now i just fixed and added some comments

Comment: If T is not double or int, I believe the code still compiles but generate run time error. Is there anyway to generate error during compile time? For example by restricting T to types that are numerical?

Comment: @mans In short, the answer is no. You can't restrict that to numerical fundamental types.

Comment: @mans it should be possible but not easy check PostSharp, but thats mean that you will need to do check if convertable to int before compile

Comment: @gleng why not? it should be possible with PostSharp, but i am not sure i know its possible to check if properties are public etc, but still i think its possible but a bit complex

Comment: @mans other option could be VS add-in i know its time consuming but you ask if its possible